# Button in ListView(or something similar like GridView) as Item,layout_height value invalid

Tags: android

In this problem, i will describe it not using the really code but simplified.
For some reason, i create a item layout xml, and it contains only a Button xml like this below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="value"/>
```

And in the getView in adapter

```
btn = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item, null);
return btn;
```

Then i found, the btn's height is a fixed value, whatever what number i wrote in the item xml.
Why it would be this?

Comment: Why don't you use LayoutInflater.from(context).inflat(resId,parent); ?

Comment: @QAMAR In fact, i've tried replace the parameter null wit parent, which is LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resId,parent, false), it can solve the problem indeed.But firstly it must add the false(attachRoot which i dont know what it is exactly).Secondly, i wonder why the null parameter impact the result...Thank you anyway.